# Is there a way to insert org-mode template with current timestamp?

Tags: datetime, emacs, org-mode

Is it possible to insert a template in org-mode by typing `<e` and hitting `<TAB>`, which would result to:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ERSTELLT: [2020-11-17 Di 21:18]
:END:
```

By looking to these references:

[Org-mode template expansions for easy code block insertion](https://www.nicholasvanhorn.com/posts/org-structure-completion.html)

[Creating Org Mode Structure Templates](https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2016/11/23/creating-org-mode-structure-templates.html),

I was able to define my own template, but without a timestamp:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:ERSTELLT:
:END:
```

The function to insert a timestamp is: `(org-time-stamp '(16) t)`, however it evaluates at org-mode start time and keeps inserting the same timestamp:

```
(eval-after-load 'org
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'org-structure-template-alist
          (list "r"
             (concat ":PROPERTIES:\n"
                     ":ERSTELLT: " (org-time-stamp '(16) t) "\n"
                     ":END:" )
             ))))
```

Emacs version: `GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, i686-w64-mingw32) of 2020-04-03`

Org-mode version: `9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542)`

Comment: The format (and versatility) of `org-structure-template-alist` has changed  in Org 9.2: the above references use the *old* version which is now obsolete. The rationale was that there are other template expansion mechanism (e.g tempo and yasnippets) so Org mode did not need to have yet another one. You might be better off *not* using `org-structure-template-alist` at all: even if you can in your current version, you will not be able to once you upgrade. But do edit your question and add the Org mode version you are using: that should help people figure out what to suggest.

Comment: @NickD thank you, I think I will need to update my emacs and use yasnippet instead =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off defining a [capture template](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) for this purpose. It really depends on what your trying to do. Often, you will get better answers if you briefly outline what the actual outcome/functionality is you want rather than just part of what you think may be the solution.

Org's capture template system is quite flexible and powerful and can make it easy to add new entries, property draws, deadlines etc. It also supports a wide range of %- control sequences for doing things like setting properties, adding active and inactive timestamps, capturing links, current selection, clipboard items etc.

Below is a copy of my capture template definitions to give you and idea. The expenses template uses properties and sets properties and some of the others add timestamps to entries in various places. There is a lot more which can be done with capture templates as well.

BTW I think your use of the org-time-stamp function is incorrect for what you want. Check the docs, but I think what you really want for a current time stamp is (org-time-stamp t t)

```
(setq org-capture-templates
  (quote
   (("t" "todo" entry
     (file+headline "~/Documents/org-data/refile.org" "Tasks")
     "* TODO %?\n\n %a"
     :empty-lines-after 1)
    ("r" "respond" entry
     (file+headline "~/Documents/org-data/refile.org" "Tasks")
     "* NEXT Respond to %:from\n SCHEDULED: %t\n\n %:subject\n %i\n %? \n %a"
     :empty-lines-after 1)
    ("n" "note" entry
     (file "~/Documents/org-data/notes.org")
     "* %U %? :NOTE:\n\n %i\n %a"
     :empty-lines-after 1)
    ("p" "phone" entry
     (file+headline "~/Documents/org-data/refile.org" "Comms")
     "* Pone: %? :PHONE:\n\n"
     :empty-lines-after 1 :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
    ("e" "expense" entry
     (file+headline "~/Documents/org-data/refile.org" "Expenses")
     "* Expense: %^{Description} :EXPENSE:\n :PROPERTIES:\n :Description: %\\1\n :Date: %u\n :Amount: %^{Amount}\n :END:\n\n | Date | %u |\n | Description | %\\1 |\n | Amount | %\\2 |\n"
     :empty-line-after 1)
    ("m" "mail" entry
     (file+headline "~/Documents/org-data/refile.org" "Comms")
     "* %U Mail:%? %:subject \n\n From %:from\n\n %i\n %a"
     :empty-lines-after 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are thinking about this like a template?

It looks like you are just trying to insert a property, which you can do with the following:

```
(org-entry-put (point) "ERSTELLT" (format-time-string "[%Y-%M-%d %a %H:%M]" (float-time)))
```

This will insert the property "ERSTELLT" for the headline under the current point (and make a new `:PROPERTIES:` drawer if necessary) with the current epoch time formatted to an org-mode timestamp. If you wanted a different timestamp, you could replace `(float-time)` with any integer you want representing the epoch time.

You wouldn't be able to insert the properties drawer anywhere you wanted like a template, but I'm not sure why you would need to given that properties drawers only make sense as part of a headline.

Comment: The reason I am using these properties is because orgzly app for android automatically creates them, and when syncing to desktop they are often useful for searching.